# How to find standard basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $S=\{u_1,u_2,u_3\},$ which is a basis for a subspace $V.$

Let $v,w \in V$ be two vectors in $V$ such that $(v)_S  =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ -1\end{pmatrix},$ and $(w)_S  =   \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1 \\ -3\end{pmatrix}.$

Let $u= 2v+w.$ How do I find $(u)_S?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The representations of $v$ and $w$ mean

$$v = u_1 + 2u_2 - u_3, w = u_2 -3u_3$$

so

$$2v+w = 2(u_1 + 2u_2 - u_3) + (u_2 -3u_3) = \\
(2u_1 + 4u_2 -2u_3) + (u_2 - 3u_3) = 2u_1 + 5u_2 - 5u_3$$

so $$(u)_s = \begin{pmatrix} 2\\5\\-5\end{pmatrix}$$

which we also could have computed as

$$2(v)_S + (w)_S$$ in $\Bbb R^3$ to save us some time. It's all linear after all... and $v \to (v)_S$ is an isomorphism between $V$ and $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $u=2v+w$ and we are dealing with *linear* algebra, $u(s)=2v(s)+w(s)$.